# How to remove certain elements from innerHTML, based on custom attribute?

Tags: javascript, html

Is there anyway to remove the links from `innerHTML` where custom attribute `data-promo` value is `1`? Output result `onclick` of the button should be:

10:00am

11:00am

12:00pm

Any help would be appreciated.

You can find a Fiddle of what I've tried so far [here](https://jsfiddle.net/La89hd03/).

```js
function day(item) {
  var data = item.getAttribute('data-value');
  document.getElementById('time-wrap').innerHTML = document.getElementById(data).innerHTML;
}
```

```html
<div style="display:none;" id="2017_12_9">
  <a class="even" onclick="times(this)" data-promo="0">10:00am</a><br>
  <a class="even" onclick="times(this)" data-promo="1">10:30am</a><br>
  <a class="even" onclick="times(this)" data-promo="0">11:00am</a><br>
  <a class="even" onclick="times(this)" data-promo="1">11:30am</a><br>
  <a class="even" onclick="times(this)" data-promo="0">12:00pm</a><br>
</div>
<button class="datecurrentselected" onclick="day(this)" data-value="2017_12_9">Dec 09, 2017</button>
<div id="time-wrap"></div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you can do is use a CSS selector, namely one that references your custom attribute (i.e. `[data-promo="1"]`) in combination with `.querySelectorAll()` and iterating over the returned list using a `.forEach()` to remove those elements that match the selector. For example:

```js
function day(item) {
  var data = item.getAttribute('data-value');
  document.getElementById('time-wrap').innerHTML = document.getElementById(data).innerHTML;
  document.querySelectorAll('[data-promo="1"]').forEach(function(element) {
    element.parentNode.removeChild(element);
  });
}
```

```html
<div style="display:none;" id="2017_12_9">
  <a class="even" onclick="times(this)" data-promo="0">10:00am</a><br>
  <a class="even" onclick="times(this)" data-promo="1">10:30am</a><br>
  <a class="even" onclick="times(this)" data-promo="0">11:00am</a><br>
  <a class="even" onclick="times(this)" data-promo="1">11:30am</a><br>
  <a class="even" onclick="times(this)" data-promo="0">12:00pm</a><br>
</div>
<button class="datecurrentselected" onclick="day(this)" data-value="2017_12_9">Dec 09, 2017</button>
<div id="time-wrap"></div>
```

There is a thing that bothers me slightly, which is the `<br>` tags that are outside the `<a>` tags, effectively creating empty lines. You can use some creative CSS tricks or Javascript to remove them, but I would suggest tweaking your HTML structure (i.e. putting them inside the link tags). Your call, however.